# Remove last character from a variable and then multiply against another variable

Tags: php, html, math

I have a whole bunch of percentages stored as XX% (e.g. 12%, 50%, etc..) I need to remove the percentage sign and then multiply the percent against another variable thats just a number (e.g. 1000, 12000) and then output the result. Is there a simple way to strip the percentage sign and then calculate the output with PHP? Or should I consider some sort of JS solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [**preg_replace_callback**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) as:

```
$input = '12%, 50%';  
$input = preg_replace_callback("|(\d+)%|","replace_precent",$input);

echo $input; // 12000, 50000

function replace_precent($matches) {
  return $matches[1] * 1000;
}
```

Comment: replacing the percent sign would be * 100 no?

Comment: @SeanJA: Right :) but the OP mentions in the question `1000, 12000`

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim):

```
$value = ((int) rtrim('12%', '%')) * 1000';
```

**Edit**

You don't strictly need to call rtrim() , as it casts to an int ok with the percentage sign. It is probably cleaner to strip it though.

```
var_dump (12 === (int) '12%');
//output: bool(true)
```

Comment: I thought casting it would work.  Now I don't have to add another duplicate answer.  I do wonder which is faster - trim, cast, string manipulation or grep.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$number = str_replace('%', '', '100%');
$result = intval($number) * 5000; // or whatever number
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [trim()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) or [str_replace()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) in PHP you can remove the percent sign. Then, you should be able to multiply the resulting number (php is weakly typed after all).

```
<?php
    $number = str_replace("%", "", $percentString);
    $newNumber = ((int) $number) * 1000;
    echo $newNumber;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).  You can also pass an array of subjects into str_replace to have them all replaced.

```
<?php
    $number = str_replace("%", "", $percentage);
    $result = $number * $other_var;
    print $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$input=array('15%','50%','10.99%','21.5%');
$multiplier=1000;

foreach($input as $n){
    $z=floatval($n)*$multiplier;
    print("$z<br>");
}

?>
```